# Driver Installation

Tags: printing

I'm using Canon LBP3108B Lasershot printer. I have download the adriver from its official website but am unable to install these drivers. Can anybody teel me how can I install these drivers in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I Googled that just to see if there was anything peculiar about your printer that would make finding it within the built-in printer utility difficult.  I honestly cannot tell, but the number of advisories online suggests there may be something tricky.  I don't have your printer handy to test this with but of the various tutorials I found just now, [this one](http://www.unixmen.com/installation-canon-lbp2900-on-linux/) looks the most promising.

Comment: this method doesn't work. Kindly tell me another way. or have I need to change my printer?

Comment: Not trying to be rude.  I suspect it is something you are doing and not the fault of the canon drivers, so maybe you should try to find a local person who is willing to try to follow the instructions.  Personally I'm not a fan of modern canon printers, or brother, and certainly not lexmark.  If you would like a printer recommendation, that's something I can do.  Every printer manufacturer has made at least one mistake.  It happens.  Mostly Epson printers are excellent and HP printers are nearly as good on average.  I am personally a big fan of the Epson WF-2540 both for its features and price.